# Python - Append 2 columns of CSV together

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a csv file into a data frame using pandas.

An example dataframe is this:

```
X           Y
1           4
2           5
3           6
```

I wish to append these two columns into a new column:

```
X           Y          Z
1           4          1
2           5          2
3           6          3
                       4
                       5
                       6
```

How can this be done using python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do that:

```
res = pd.concat([df, df.melt()["value"]], axis=1)
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
     X    Y  value
0  1.0  4.0      1
1  2.0  5.0      2
2  3.0  6.0      3
3  NaN  NaN      4
4  NaN  NaN      5
5  NaN  NaN      6
```

Comment: Did it answer your question?